# JPOS when to disable, release and close printer

Tags: java, javapos

My application is a POS system with a single terminal using a single printer. Question is when is it appropriate to call `open(),` `claim()` and `setDeviceEnabled(true)` and `setDeviceEnabled(false)`, `release()` and `close()`. Now I do it before and after each print. Should I have it open through multiple prints and `release()` and `close()` at the end of the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the software structure of the application.

If the application that uses the printer has only one process, execute `Open()`, `Claim()`, `DeviceEnabled=True` once at application startup.
You can execute `DeviceEnabled=False`, `Release()`, `Close()` just before the application terminates.

If necessary, the application combines `TransactionPrint()`, `RotatePrint()`, `PrintNormal()`, etc. to print.

This shortens the time it takes for printing.

If applications using printers are running concurrently in more than one process at the same time, only `Open()` in each processes.

If the process requiring printing remains almost unchanged, `Claim()` and `DeviceEnabled=True` on the side of acquiring the control right of the printer simultaneously with the timing of switching of the job and the screen, the side for releasing the control right of the printer With `DeviceEnabled=False`, `Release()` is called.

When processes requiring printing change frequently, `Claim()`, `DeviceEnabled=True` is executed after every use of the printer occurs, and after printing is completed, when necessary printing is finished, `DeviceEnabled=False`, `Release()` to hold.